# What is the best way to bulk check for Firestore documents, and if not created add a document?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am adding an integration to an app and want to add an initial fetch of all data from the API, check in my app if any entries exist, and then create new entries or update existing entries with data from the API. I looked through the documentation on batch transactions/writes, but it seems to be mostly concerning making batched writes to a single document. Email addresses would be the item to search for in the existing database entries.

I would think this would be some version of a Firestore query .where('email', '==', API_EMAIL), but not sure how to efficiently handle potential several-hundred document updates after that.

Comment: Have you looked into Transactions and batched writes? `https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions`

Answer (score 0):

Firestore and all Google Cloud Platform will do all the possible performance problems related to queries that you might have, so you don't need to worry about this point.

Regarding reading multiple documents at once, you can use transactions to do that. This option provides you the feature to read more than one document at once. Considering that, I would like to recommend you to take a look again at the documentation [Updating data with transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) and focus on the transactions, to confirm if that's what you are looking for.

Let me know if the information helped you!